# Given that $x_0$ is a real root of $x^3+px + q = 0$, how can I show that $p^2 \geq 4x_0q$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, examples-counterexamples, cubics

> Given a equation $x^3 + px + q = 0$ and $x_0$  as a real root of this equation, how can I show that $p^2 \geq 4{x_0}q$ ?

My attempt:

Since this equation has at least one real root, it must then have a discriminant greater or equal to 0 (*not true as the fellas bellow pointed), this led me to $4p^3 + 27q^2 \leq 0$ but I'm not sure how to get to the other relation, and I don't even know if this is the right approach.

Comment: A cubic equation with real coefficients has always at least one real root. So the sign ot the discriminant does not matter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another approach that is more obvious with a shallower analysis.

\begin{align}
x^3 + 0 x^2 + px + q 
&= (x-x_0)(x^2+bx+c)\\
&= x^3 +(b-x_0)x^2 + (c-bx_0)x-x_0 c
\end{align}

It implies that

\begin{cases}
0=b-x_0\\
p=c-bx_0\\
q=-x_0 c
\end{cases}

Combining these three equations we have

$$
p=-\frac{q}{x_0}-x_0^2
$$

Now we need to prove that $p^2-4x_0q\geq 0$. Note that $x_0$ and $q$ are real numbers.

\begin{align}
p^2-4x_0q
 &= \left(-\frac{q}{x_0}-x_0^2\right)^2  -4x_0q \\
 &= x_0^4+2x_0q+\frac{q^2}{x_0^2}-4x_0q \\
 &= x_0^4-2x_0q+\frac{q^2}{x_0^2}\\
 &= \left(x_0^2-\frac{q}{x_0}\right)^2 \geq 0
\end{align}

Q.E.D

For $x_0=0$, the inequality still  holds,
$$p^2-4x_0q=c^2\geq 0$$

Comment: +1.  For a little less algebraic effort, you can observe $x_0=b$ from your first equation. Substituting into the others gives
$$\left.\begin{align}
p &= c - b^2 \\
q &= -b c
\quad\end{align}\right\}
\quad\to\quad  p^2-4x_0q=(c-b^2)^2+4b^2c = (c+b^2)^2 \geq 0$$ No need to consider $x_0=0$ as a separate case.

Comment: @Blue: Thank you. A nice spot!

Comment: thank you, I had got until that equation (p = -(q/x0 - x0^2) but I got stuck, this clarified my question.

Comment: @user276684: You are welcome. :-)

Answer (score 13):

If $x^{3}+px+q=0$ has a real root $x_{0}$, then a quadratic equation $x_{0}x^{2}+px+q=0$ have real roots and one of them is $x_{0}$ i.e. its discriminant is non negative.

$p^{2}-4x_{0}q\geq 0$

Comment: Where  did this  quadratic equation come from ?

Comment: @user276684 the inequality in the question hinted at quadratic equation discriminant. Thus I try to make the cubic into quadratic equation

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja I guess your solution now fits the edited question.

Comment: It needs a special treatment when $x_0=0$ in which $x_0x^2+px+q=0$ is no longer a quadratic equation. :-)

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity does not matter, discriminant still needs to be non negative :)

Comment: Linear equation $px+q=0$ has no discriminant that can be defined.

Comment: @Artificial Stupidity But the case $x_0=0$ easy to check.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: Yes. It is easy. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's wrong.

Take $x_0=-2\cos20^{\circ}$ as a root of $x^3-3x+1=0.$

We need to prove that $$9\leq-8\cos20^{\circ},$$ which is not so true.

Comment: A minor typo, it would be $-8\cos 20^{\circ}$

Comment: @ABCD Thank you! I fixed.

Comment: you're right, I wrote the sign flipped

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity the question was edited